# Execute API after close the browser in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, dom-events

i need to execute a Api if the browser closed, example break out, 
closing the browser from the user, crash of pc, ext ext.

**This function is in my component**, i dont call this function anywhere,I think it should automatically activate.

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    this.postService.unsetPost(this.postId).subscribe();
  }
```

But dont work.

Comment: Can you please brief what exactly you want to achieve, or why you want to fire the API on the closing of the browser?

Comment: I created a resource manager, a user cannot edit while it is already being edited,And I do it, by recording records in the db, but I don't cover the case in which the browser closes unexpectedly, because until the record exists the content is locked and nobody can modify. I have to delete this record when closes the browser, this.postService.unsetPost(int idpost) delete this record.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the better idea is making the heartbeat api that sends requests every N seconds to notify server that the session is active and the user is online. On the server check every M minutes if there was no heartbeat requests for more than N seconds: if it is so - execute the API request(what you wanted to execute on crash).

Comment: But this is due to a huge server-side load, instead is clear and light if i exectute the API (a delete in db) only when the browser or tab closes.